# Date Picker for selecting and viewing contents for that particular date

Tags: php, jquery, date, datepicker, picker

I need a date picker/selector written in php, jquery and probably mysql that is visible for the user to select a particular date and view the contents for that particular date.

An example can be found here 
http://soccernet.espn.go.com/scores/_/league/eng.1/english-premier-league?cc=3888

Another example is http://www1.skysports.com/football/fixtures-results/06-september-2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and modify it for your own purposes. There a lot of Date Pickers out there. In this case, Google will probably provide you with more answers than Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks Wayne, will go through the tutorials to get a better understanding first, just like you suggested.